# PureScript Type Error is hard to understand

Tags: purescript

This compiles

```
foo ma = case ma of
  [Just a] -> newRVar 0 >>= a

view                :: forall a eff. 
                       M.Map String (Linker Number a eff) -> 
                       String -> 
                       Eff (reactive :: Reactive | eff) Unit
view         m yaml = case parseYAML yaml           of
  Right (View xs)  -> case (flip M.lookup) m <$> xs of
    (as)       -> foo as
```

This does not

```
foo ma = case ma of
  Just a -> newRVar 0 >>= a

view                :: forall a eff. 
                       M.Map String (Linker Number a eff) -> 
                       String -> 
                       Eff (reactive :: Reactive | eff) Unit
view         m yaml = case parseYAML yaml           of
  Right (View xs)  -> case (flip M.lookup) m <$> xs of
    (as)       -> foo <$> as
```

with the following error:

```
 Cannot unify Control.Monad.Eff.Eff (reactive :: Control.Reactive.Reactive | u8437) u8438 with Prelude.Unit.
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you're putting an `Control.Monad.Eff.Eff (reactive :: Control.Reactive.Reactive | u8437) u8438` where a `Unit` should go.

Does `foo` have an type declaration? It probably won't work without one regardless of what you're doing in `view`, because of the current lack of typeclass constraint inference.

In the second case the type is:

```
foo :: forall a eff. Maybe a -> Eff (reactive :: Control.Reactive.Reactive | eff) a
```

The type of `(<$>)` is

```
(<$>) :: forall f a b. (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

And the type of `as` will be `Maybe (Linker Number a eff)`, so if you start substituting types you can see pretty quickly where it goes wrong:

```
a ~ Maybe (Linker Number a1 eff)
b ~ Eff (reactive :: Control.Reactive.Reactive | eff) (Linker Number a1 eff)
f ~ Maybe
```

So the `f b` result type of `foo <$> as` is:

```
Maybe (Eff (reactive :: Control.Reactive.Reactive | eff) (Linker Number a1 eff))
```

Comment: Ok its really Obvious now. Thank you. Sorry, I was just beating my head around my own ignorance.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that type substitution is entirely correct, but hopefully you can figure it out from there!

Comment: Well so far the type system has been the hardest part about transitioning to functional. I seem to spend 75% of my time just fighting with the type system, and in cases like this I was just lost. Sometimes I just try to write 2 logically equivalent things in different syntax's, when that does not work I'm just confused.